# Why is rigged mesh deforming when rotating both in pose mode and object mode?

Tags: rigging

So for some reason when I rotate my rigged object either in pose mode or object mode the mid section in is off kilter when rotated 180. I've attached a video of it in action and a break down of screen shots off all info I felt necessary.

So the oddity happens when I rotated the rigged object either in object mode or pose mode via Z. Now if I rotate it 180 via x then 180 via Z no deformation happens granted the object is upside down. When I then rotated 180 via Y the object is right side up, the deformation happens.

The video I used to rig the spine:  https://youtu.be/Erqgl_PQyrk

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAzW3.jpg

https://streamable.com/b2l6yv

[blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pfwx924hh07v72f/error.blend?dl=0)

Comment: hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've uploaded the blend file and provided more details on the issue: [blend file][1]


  [1]: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pfwx924hh07v72f/error.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

So found out the root cause it was the the space in the driver that affected it. Originally it was set to world, but when updating it to local/transform space. the oddity corrected it self. video attached show it

[Video demostration](https://streamable.com/6uy0sn)